# How to login a https server using python

Tags: python, authentication, https, web-crawler

I want to capture some webpage, but that is **https based and require user and password** authentication.

I have user and password, but have no idea how to use that in python script.

Coudl anybody share some example script for this?

Comment: HTTPS has nothing to do with requiring username/passwords (aside from being _necessary_ to prevent MITM attacks). The right way to provide your credentials depends on how the web page requests them. HTTP basic auth? A POSTed form? Something else?

Comment: thank you for the quick response, i need take a deep look at this quesiton and get back later.